# invalid use of template-name without an argument list

Tags: c++, templates

So i have a class name repository which is just a simple array.Here is a part of the class:

```
template<class Element>
class repository {
private:
    int size;
    int capacity;
    Element* elements;
```

I have another class named participant.I want to have a repository of participants and perform actions on that repository using a new class named controller.But I don`t know how to declare the type of the repository in the controller.

Here is a part of the class participant:

```
class participant {
private:
    int position;
    int score;
```

And here is a part from the class controller:

```
#include "repository.h"
#include "participant.h"
class controller {
private:
    repository repository;
    repository temporary;
    void createCopy();
public:
    controller();
    controller(repository repo);
```

And I get the errors:

-invalid use of template-name 'repository' without an argument list int the lines with repository repository and repository temporary;

-expected ')' before 'repo' in the line with controller(repository repo);

How should I declare  the type for the repository and temporary in the declaration of class controller so that I won`t get any other errors?

Comment: welcome to SO! If answers are useful, please mark them up. If not, then please give some feedback. If an anwser answers your question to your satisfaction, you can accept it. It makes it more likely that others will answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repository is a class template, so you need to declare your data members as

```
private:
    repository<SomeType> repository; // but this hides repository name
    repository<SomeType> temporary;  // repository has another meaning now!
```

where `SomeType` in this case is probably `participant`. `repository` by itself doesn't name a type, `repository<int>` or `repository<std::string>` etc. does. Next, your data member name cannot be `repository`, since that is the template name needed for `temporary`. So change the name of the data member:

```
private:
    repository<SomeType> repo_;
```

Likewise, your constructor must take a type:

```
controller(repository<participant> repo);
```

although you probably want to pass `repo` by const reference:

```
controller(const repository<participant>& repo);
```

Comment: i have already tried that.after i type repository<participant> repository; i get new error messages in the class controller such as:'repository<participant> controller::repository' is private
and declaration of 'repository<participant> controller::repository' [-fpermissive],but also i get now an error in the class repository saying that changes meaning of 'repository' from 'class repository<participant>' [-fpermissive].I`m really new into programming in c++ so i really don`t know why i have this errors.

Comment: @ironflower could you try giving your private data member a name different to "repository"?